# inject static content word document while mail merge is running?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The rules available for mail merge in ms word 2007 appear to be limiting. I have created a mail merge to fetch about 10000 rows of data from excel and merge this data into word document by using a mail merge. This works as expected I have even used some conditional statements to display default text when a field is empty. However, I have been asked to insert a static page every 50th page which would include messaging not provided in excel file. When this static text appears on page 50, then 100, then 150 etc it would be static text and no other fields from merge  would appear on page. In other words these fields would be replaced by static text.  Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking I could code something in vba and create a new page on the fly when a certain page number is reach ex. 50

Thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can interfere in the mail merge process. Therefore you should write code to call MailMerge in batches of 50 (instead of one batch of 10,000). Create a loop to call 200 batches of 50, and then insert creation of a totally different document after each batch has been done.

Comment: great how can I trigger mailmerge from vba within word? Are you thinking of calling mailmerge from another office product such as excel? I've tried finding vba code for the mail merge in the word document, but can't find any hooks to tie into (no mail merge code) , which makes this more challenging. 

Thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code on the Internet. Start with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836701.aspx). If you google for "VBA MailMerge" you will also come across a number of links to threads in StackOverflow dealing with calling MailMerge from Excel. I suggest you focus on a method in which you imagine that you would like to work and research the code that might do the job. You will then arrive quickly at a stage where you actually might need the kind of help that is being offered here to abundantly.